# How to work with factors in matrices in R

Tags: r, facet

I'm debugging someone else's code in R. I have data in a matrix called `seg` which looks like this-
`head(seg)`

> id | chr | start | end | test | ref | position | log2
>
> 102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 1 | 100350001 | 101250000 | 986 | 1933 | 100800000 | -0.179835
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 1 | 100800001 | 101700000 | 1104 | 2113 | 101250000 | -0.145205
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 1 | 101250001 | 102150000 | 1062 | 1874 | 101700000 | -0.0279899
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 1 | 101700001 | 102600000 | 893 | 1610 | 102150000 | -0.0589814
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 1 | 102150001 | 103050000 | 737 | 1394 | 102600000 | -0.128147

He is useing `facet_grid(id~chr)` in his plots, and one of the problems is that the order of the chromosomes is not right, they are sorted alphabetically (which means that chromosomes 10-19 appear before chromosomes 2-9, and so on), the levels of the chr column are in the wrong order.
`levels(seg$chr)`

> [1] "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "2"  "20" "21" "22" "3"  "4"
>
> [18] "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "M"  "X"  "Y"

I tried to change the order of the levels, but when I did that, the data also changed, if for example I'd try this `levels(seg$chr) = c(22:1, "M", "X", "Y")`

`head(seg)`

> id | chr | start | end | test | ref | position | log2
>
> 102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 22 | 100350001 | 101250000 | 986 | 1933 | 100800000 | -0.179835
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 22 | 100800001 | 101700000 | 1104 | 2113 | 101250000 | -0.145205
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 22 | 101250001 | 102150000 | 1062 | 1874 | 101700000 | -0.0279899
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 22 | 101700001 | 102600000 | 893 | 1610 | 102150000 | -0.0589814
>   102G.bam.vs.ref1.hits | 22 | 102150001 | 103050000 | 737 | 1394 | 102600000 | -0.128147

So if for instance I use `levels(seg$chr) = c(1:22, "M", "X", "Y")` the labels will be right, but all the data from chromosome 10 will be referring to chromosome 2.

I want the data to stay as it is, and only change the order of the factor levels (order of the plot) , I'm probably missing something very basic about how to work with factors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to avoid this, not very elegant, but it works.
Instead of changing the factor levels directly like I did, I created a new factor, with the same data, and replaced the previous one with it.

Instead of this-
`levels(seg$chr) = c(1:22, "M","X","Y")`
which changed the factor itself, and also the data.
I used this-
`seg$chr = factor(seg$chr, levels = c(1:22, "M","X","Y"))`
which created a new factor, with the same data, only that this time the levels were in the wright order.

If there is a better solution, I'd be happy to hear about it.
:)
Thanks!